# How to make operations between part of array with part of array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([2,3,4,6,7,4,5,3,2,1,9,8,7,6,4,2])
## a has 16 elements
b=np.array([1,5,3,7])
""" i want this:
 a[:4] - b[1], a[4:8]-b[2], a[8:12]-b[3], a[12:16]-b[4] in one array
and it should look like
c=numpy.array[1,2,3,5,2,-1,0,-2....]
```

This is just a simple example for my problem. So can not be done with using groups. I need a loop to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape your array `a`, make operations on that and than flatten back.

```
In [24]: import numpy as np

In [25]: a=np.array([2,3,4,6,7,4,5,3,2,1,9,8,7,6,4,2])

In [26]: b=np.array([1,5,3,7])

In [27]: (a.reshape(4,4).T - b).T.ravel()
Out[27]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  5,  2, -1,  0, -2, -1, -2,  6,  5,  0, -1, -3, -5])
```

Comment: Oh thanks very much. Can i ask u a one more question please? i have a list [[1,2],[3,4]], how can i make it [1,2,3,4]?

Comment: @SelcukYalcinkaya, if this is a python list, a common approach is: `from itertools import chain` and `list(chain(*[[1,2],[3,4]]))`.

Comment: Uhm yes it's a python list but my list is longer than i can type, that was just an example. will this for like this ? list(chain(*a)) if a is the list if i want to make chain?